# Sanity check: correctly downgrading Java in conda environment

Tags: java, anaconda, conda

I want to downgrade from Java 10 to Java 7 for one of my conda environments. I created a copy of an old environment, and now want to downgrade the Java version. Originally I was hoping I could do something like:

```
conda create --name new-env --clone old-env java=1.7
```

But that's not possible. Instead, I think I'm supposed to download Java 1.7 and then just change the JAVA_HOME environment variable in my new environment. Is this correct?

Thanks for your help!